# Which Version ( ISO ) to Install with VMware Fusion?

Tags: iso, vmware-fusion

Apologies if this question has already been asked.

I'm looking to install Ubuntu from ISO to be used with VMware Fusion.
I'm using a Mac Pro with El Capitan as my base OS.

My main goal with Ubuntu is to freshen my knowledge of Linux as I primarily am looking to get into Linux/Security Administration. In a previous life I was a Unix Admin where we used Tuxedo as our desktop environment.

Any gotchas, recommendations ?

Thanks!

mrmodularus.

Answer (score 4):

Install any of the currently supported versions. They all should work.

There are four supported versions currently: 12.04, 14.04, 15.10 and 16.04.

12.04, 14.04 and 16.04 are all LTS (long-term support) releases, which have pretty self-explanatory descriptions.

- 12.04 will be supported until mid-2017.
- 14.04 will be supported until mid-2019.
- 16.04 will be supported until mid-2021.

15.10 is *not* an LTS release. Normal releases are supported for about 9 months. 15.10 was released October 2015. If you install 15.10, you'll have to upgrade to 16.04 once the end-of-life date comes.

LTS releases only let you upgrade to a new version of Ubuntu (by default) if the new version is another LTS. Even then, it waits until the LTS has reached x.04.1 before prompting you to upgrade. If you need stability, go with LTS.

Non-LTS releases prompt you to upgrade on each new release, which is every 6 months. These are good for getting new features, drivers, kernels and programs, but are not the nest option for stability. If you upgrade from a non-LTS release to an LTS release, you will still be prompted every 6 months to upgrade. Use a non-LTS if you like new features and are more into experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

I generally recommend using last stable LTS version, thus Ubuntu 14.04

Download: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Answer (score 1):

While @Zacharee1 post mentiones already the most relevant facts i would like to add that it might make sense to install the **server** version instead of the **desktop** ones.
Its basically just a smaller amount of default packages.

It gives you the option to start a bit more from scratch and have something small to get started - choosing & installing a desktop environment by yourself etc...

I would choose **14.04 LTS** - as it gives you the option to do an entire upgrade from LTS to LTS (14.04 to 16.04) as well as another playground.